# can't set custom cookie with secure flag for android's webview

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I'm using Android API 21, and I can't set custom cookie with secure flag.

This code can set cookie properly

```
final CookieManager cm = CookieManager.getInstance();
cm.setAcceptCookie(true);
m.setCookie("https://www.google.com", "test-cookie=non-secure;");
final WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

But if I change

```
m.setCookie("https://www.google.com", "test-cookie=non-secure;");
```

with

```
m.setCookie("https://www.google.com", "test-cookie=secure; secure");
```

then it doesn't work. I'm not sure what's wrong, please help me fix this. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. Anyone?